# Error on Xcode when I press on any image on my Cordova app

Tags: xcode, image, cordova, button, hyperlink

The error as follow:

```
[com.apple.VisionKit.processing] MADService: VisualSearchGating: Could not get visual search result from MADService with Error Domain=VisualIntelligence.EligibilityError Code=0 "(null)"
```

Comment: Same here when I do a long press on an image on CapacitorJS instead of Cordova, I tried this plugin:
https://github.com/Nikita-schetko/capacitor-suppress-longpress-gesture

This link has interesting infos:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3208